# Tornar-se vs Ficar

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras, diferenças

I am confused as regards the difference between the verbs ***tornar-se*** and ***ficar*** when trying to convey the English verb; *become*. For example:

> *Ele **ficou** contente depois de ouvir as boas notícias* = He **became** pleased after hearing the good news.

However...

> *Ele **tornou-se** um médico de classe mundial* = He **became** a world-class
>   doctor.

When should I use ***tornar-se***, and when should I use ***ficar***?

What is more, are the other forms of saying *become* (such as ***pôr-se*** & **fazer-se**) used?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I am a native Portuguese speaker, and this is the very first time I've ever thought of the difference between ***tornar-se*** and ***ficar***. I think I got it. (Ok, eight months afte I wrote this answer I can say that it is broadly consistent with the massive *Gramática do Português*, Fundação Calouste Gulbenkian, 2013, pp. 1315-8; I’ll just add a little quote further down.)

You use ***tornar-se*** if you become a different person; you use ***ficar*** to say that you are now in a different, usually temporary, state, but are still the same person as before.  Also, ***tornar-se*** suggests a slow change, whereas ***ficar*** suggests a more sudden change. [This article in Veja has more.](http://veja.abril.com.br/blog/sobre-palavras/consultorio/as-sutis-diferencas-entre-ficar-e-tornar-se/)

> (a) *Ele **tornou-se** um médico de classe mundial*. If you become a world-class doctor you are in a way a different person from what you were before.
>
> (b) *Ele **ficou** contente depois de ouvir as boas notícias.* He got happy. So he is now in a different state, but you would not expect his nature to have changed in a fundamental way.
>
> (c) *Ele **tornou-se** um homem irritável*. He aquired an irritable disposition, and now gets angry easily.
>
> (d) *Ele **ficou** irritado com o teu comportamento*. He got angry, but did not become an angry man.
>
> (e) Ele tornou-se (um homem) sujo. He became a dirty man (a man who's usually dirty).
>
> (f) Ele ficou sujo. He got dirty.

There is a relationship between ***tornar-se*** and ***ficar*** and [***ser*** and ***estar***](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1062/difference-between-ser-and-estar). If *ele **tornou-se** something*, now *ele **é** ou **foi** something*. If *ele **ficou** something* then *ele **está** ou **esteve** something*. So:

> (a') *Ele **tornou-se** um médico de classe mundial. E era convidado para conferências por **ser** um médico de classe mundial.*
>
> (b´) *Ele **ficou** contente depois de ouvir as boas notícias.* Depois a namorada chegou perguntou-lhe "*por que razão **estás** tão contente*?"
>
> (c') *Ele **tornou-se** um homem irritável. E as pessoas evitava-no porque ele **era** um homem irritável*
>
> (d´) *Ele ficou **irritado**. Então a namorada disse "ele **está** muito irritado, ainda faz algum disparate."*
>
> (e') *Ele **tornou-se** um homem sujo. Agora ele **é** um homem sujo*
>
> (f') *Ele **ficou** sujo. A mãe quando o viu disse "**estás** tão sujo, vai já lavar-te e mudar de roupa.*"

So, typically ***tornar-se*** leads to ***ser***, and ***ficar*** leads to ***estar***. But ***ser*** and ***estar*** don't make any reference to the *becoming*. The *Gramática do Português* (Fundação Calouste Gulbenkian, 2013, pp. 1317-8) makes the same point with an example that mirrors my (e) and (f), *ele tornou-se sujo/ficou sujo* (my boldface):

> Note-se também que em *a Maria tornou-se triste*, o adjetivo é reinterpretado como denotando um estado estável; ou seja, infere-se que, depois da mudança, a Maria **é uma pessoa triste**; não que **está triste** (esta última inferência obtém-se de *a Maria ficou triste*).
>
> [My translation:] Note too that in *a Maria tornou-se triste*, the adjective is reinterpreted as denoting a stable state; that is, one infers that after the change Maria is a sad person; not that she is in a sad mood (we would make this last inference from *a Maria ficou triste*).

In some cases both ***tornar-se*** and ***ficar*** feel natural:

*Ele **tornou-se/ficou** famoso com a publicação do seu último livro*. I suppose we're not quite sure whether *being famous* is an inherent or accidental feature of his.

You can use ***ficar*** in place of ***tornar-se*** if you're talking of change in degree rather than nature:

> *Ele **tornou-se/ficou** ainda mais irritável depois do divórcio.*

***Fazer-se*** suggests a slow development, and can often replace, sometimes advantageously, ***tornar-se***: *ela **fez-se** uma excelente profissional*.

***Pôr-se*** can replace ***ficar*** in some idiomatic expressions where the change is under one's control: *põe-te/fica quieto* (be still), *vê se te pões/ficas bom depressa* (make sure you get well soo, said as encouragement to someone who's sick).

Now, I'm pretty sure someone will find exceptions to what I've written. Also, I'm from Portugal, and some of my examples may sound more or less natural to Brazilian ears. But I hope this helps.

Comment: Okay I understand. So similarly to ser vs estar, tornar-se denotes a sense of greater permanence, and is more of a total transformation of person than Ficar. Great explanation, thanks much.

Comment: @MrChasi I think the analogy with ser/estar is inapposite. The contrast is transformation vs. final state. The contrast in ser estar is temporary/permanent. In a way, if you focus on a transformation, the transformation is probably longer and the state is then probably more permanent. But we're then a few links removed.

Comment: Focus on transformation/state was my first thought, but as I surveyed more and more examples I concluded that, while that is generally true, it is changes in essence (ser) versus changes in accidental features (estar) that matters. Even if you want to focus on state you won't say _ele ficou um grande homem/médico/excelente profissional._ Or even if you want to focus on a non-essencial transformation  you wouldn't say _ao longo de um duro dia de trabalho ele tornou-se cansado/faminto/sujo_, you'd say _foi ficando_ instead.

Comment: If you say _ele tornou-se sujo_  you mean he became a person who doesn´t look after himself and is usually dirty, not that he got dirty for a while while working and before washing. It does focus more on his becoming so than _ele é sujo_, but the crucial difference relative to _ele ficou sujo_ is that in the latter you expect him to wash and get clean again.

Comment: If you say, ele "tornou-se um grande médico", I definitely see an emphasis on transformation. Otherwise, I'd say "ele é um grande médico". Indeed, "ficar" doesn't work there, but I guess it's because there's always a process involved in becoming a doctor. Though maybe the contrast is more along the lines of becoming a thing vs becoming a state. As for your transformation example with "ficar", you're cheating, what gives it a progressive aspect is "ir + gerúndio".

Comment: I also think you're confusing the transformation with process of the transformation. Indeed, "tornar-se" doesn't need to have a progressive aspect to it unless you add *mais e mais*, *sucessivamente*, and so on.

Comment: @MrChasi I now have the massive Gramática do Português. I think you'l be pleased to know that its two and a half pages on this issue back up my answer.

Comment: @Jacinto ah ok. What is that; where can I access it?

Comment: @MrChasi I think it exists in paper form only. 2,400 pages in two volumes, and a third volume to come at some point. I added a quote in my answer, backing up the point that has proved more controversial.

Answer (score 10):

The main difference is that **tornar-se** has more focus on the transformation (but not necessarily with some progressive aspect), whereas **ficar** focuses on the final state. Remember that *tornar* can also be used in a similar way to "to turn" in sentences such as "ele tornou esta empresa numa das mais sucedidas no ramo".

As you may imagine, this still leaves quite a margin for overlap.

I assume you're referring to *become* in the OED sense 5. Let's look at the definition and the examples:

> 5. To come to be (something or in some state).
>
> ✝ a. with *to*, *into*. *Obs.* [...]
>
> b. with *subst.* or *adj. complement*.
>
> - [...] (too old for me to understand)
> - *c* **1350** *Wilt. Palern.* 881 881 He cast al his colour and bicom
>     pale.
> - **1398** TREVISA *Barth.* *De P. R.* v. lxii. (1495) 178 Goddis sone bycame man and dwellyd among us.
> - **1483** CAXTON *Gold. Leg.* I35/4 So wyse a man is such a fole becomen.
> - **1549** *Compl. Scot.* 2 The universal pepil ar be cum
>     distitute of Justice.
> - **1611** BIBLE *Gen.* xix. 26 His wife looked backe .. she became a pillar of salt.
> - **1625** BACON *Ess.* (Arb) 479 Their Boughs were becommen too great.
> - **1717** LADY M. W. Montague *Lett.* II. xlvi. 30 The asmack, or Turkish veil, is become .. agreeable to me.
> - **1774** CHESTERF. *Lett.* I. ii Unfortunately for her, she became in love with him.
> - **1810** HENRY *Elem. Chem.* (1840) II. 699 When .. more
>     largely diluted with water, it becomes hot.
> - **1848** MACAULAY *Hist. Eng.* 1. 4 When first they became known to the Tyrian mariners.
> - **1876** GREEN *Short Hist.* vi. §4. 298 Florence .. became the home of an intellectual Revival.

Note that these are historical citations and some of these sentences use the auxiliary "to be" instead of "to have".

I think the distinction between *something* and *state* that the dictionary does can help us. With *becoming **something***, *torna-se* will usually be the right word; and for _becoming **some state**, *ficar*.

So in Portuguese:

- Ele perdeu toda a sua cor e ficou pálido. *("tornou-se pálido" would mean "tornou-se uma pessoa pálida", so a more permanent change)*
- Pouco depois, Goddis tornou-se homem e viveu entre nós.
- Um homem tão sábio tornou-se tão tolo.
- O (?) universal ficou destituído de justiça.
- A sua mulher olhou para trás .. tornou-se uma estátua de sal. *(or "**numa** estátua de sal")*
- Os seus ramos (?) tinham-se tornado grandes demais. *("tinham ficado" is also possible, but I see here a gradual process where the boughs get bigger and bigger)*
- O véu turco tornou-se .. aceitável/adequado para mim. *(the original has the present participle, which suggests it was a process. Actually you could never use "ficar" here. At some point something is acceptable or it isn't -- so you would use "ser"; it can become acceptable through time though, and then you would use "tornar-se")*.
- Infelizmente para ela, ficou apaixonada por ele.
- Quando mais diluído em água, fica quente. *(or "torna-se", if we want to focus on the process)*
- Quando os marinheiros de Tiro ficaram pela primeira vez familiarizados com eles.
- Florença ... tornou-se o lar de uma renascença intelectual.

Comment: `When first they became known to the Tyrian mariners.` significa "quando os marinheiros de Tiro os conheceram (...)", e não "quando eles conheceram (...) os de Tiro".

Comment: @ANeves Obrigado pela correção. Tive foi de dar a volta à frase para conseguir usar "ficar".

Comment: I do agree that _tornar-se_ focus more on the transformation, and _ficar_ on the ensuing state, as you can tell from my 2nd paragraph. But that may not help much a foreign speaker to choose which verb to use. Now consider these:_ao longo dum duro dia de trabalho ele (a) tornou-se um enxertador competente (plant grafter). Depois ele (b) ficou um enxertador competente._ Now this _ao longo dum duro dia de trabalho ele (c) tornou-se cansado. Depois ele (d) ficou cansado._ (a) funciona, (c), com a mesma estrutura, não funciona. (b) não funciona, (d), com a mesma estrutura, funciona.

Comment: @Jacinto It's true, but I think the explanation is more along the line of _come to be_ **something** / **in a state**, as I mentioned in the second part and `Centaurus` put more perhaps clearly in his answer. So a more formal reason for the prefernce. Though I'm not happy with that as the whole explanation, since it's pretty easy to find examples where you can use either with an adjective or a noun, and I would classify the difference then as transformation vs state. Maybe we're missing a simpler polysemic explanation.

Comment: That's funny: your _come to be something / in a state_ translates as _vir a  **ser** alguma coisa / vir a **estar** num estado._ You're getting quite close to my own explanation.

Comment: "Goddis sone" in modern English is "God's son", not "Mr. Goddis soon".

Answer (score 9):

**Em poucas palavras** e de uma forma simples, para aquele que está aprendendo português como segunda língua.  (válido para ptBR)

Em geral, tu te tornas **"um substantivo"** e tu ficas **"um adjetivo"**

- tornou-se o dono da fábrica, um médico, o prefeito da cidade. uma celebridade, um mentiroso, um escravo de suas obsessões, um indivíduo egoísta, um mau exemplo para seus filhos. (Eu não poderia usar "ficou" nos exemplos acima)
- ficou infeliz, triste, cansado, magoada, ferida, pasma, assustado, indignado, supreso, feliz, etc.  (Não caberia o uso de "tornou-se" aqui)

Já "ficou" seguido da preposição "com", pede um substantivo

- ficou com... frio, calor, raiva, fome, vontade, desejo, inveja.

E existem as **expressões idiomáticas**:

- "ficou uma fera",
- "ficou a ver navios",
- "ficou p... da vida",
- "ficou com a pulga atrás da orelha",
- ficou chupando o dedo,
- ficou boiando (gíria),
- ficou na mesma,
- ficou na mão,
- ficou fora de si, etc.

EDIT:
E ainda, para "tornar-se", os exemplos que @Jacinto acrescentou nos comentários.

Comment: Interessante o teu ponto de vista +1

Comment: Mas: tornou-se desmazelado, preguiçoso, arrogante, invejoso, vingativo, rancoroso, quezilento, insuportável, execrável; ou muito diligente, industrioso, competente e responsável; ou conhecido, famoso e célebre.

Comment: Esta lista está longe de ser exaustiva. Basta pensares em adjetivos que descrevem o tipo de pessoa (por oposição ao estado da pessoa); muitos deles funcionam com *tornar-se*. Alguns, como *insuportável*, funcionam com *tornar-se* e com *ficar*.