# "Ficar "+ adjetivo VS "Estar" + adjetivo

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras, verbos, diferenças

Eu vi usar os verbos ***estar*** e ***ficar*** nos seguintes casos:

> O gerente ficou bravo.
>
> O menino está triste.
>
> Meu pai está bravo comigo.

Tem uma razão para em alguns casos ser usado o verbo *estar*, e em outros, o *ficar*?

Comment: "Estar" é uma das traduções do verbo *to be*, denota um estado, qualidade, etc., enquanto "ficar" aqui significa "passar a ter, ser, etc.", ou seja, *to turn/become/get etc*.

Comment: Majid, vê também a pergunta [*tornar-se* vs *ficar*](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1230/tornar-se-vs-ficar). A primeira resposta explica a relação entre *ficar* e *estar*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nesses exemplos, "ficar" enfoca a transição para o estado, enquanto "estar" enfoca a permanência no estado.

> O gerente ficou bravo.

Algo enfureceu o gerente.

> O menino está triste.

Não sabemos porque ou desde quando.

> Meu pai está bravo comigo.

O sujeito não diz porque ou desde quando o pai está bravo.

Answer (score -1):

Pelo menos aqui não Brasil (sou brasileiro) tanto faz usar os verbos estar ou ficar nestes casos.

Você poderia usar também:

O gerente estava bravo.
O menino ficou triste.
O meu pai ficou bravo comigo.

Todos também estão certos e não mudam muito o sentido da frase.

Abraços

Douglas

Comment: Mas limitar a resposta aos exemplos da pergunta não tem interesse. *Ficar* e *estar* não significam o mesmo; os exemplos da pergunta é que não são bons para ilustrar a diferença.