# "Quando é escuro" ou "quando está escuro"?

Tags: verbos, diferenças-transatlânticas, ser-estar

Existe alguma possibilidade do uso do verbo **ser** no seguinte exemplo:

> Quando **é** escuro.

Eu acredito que correto seria o uso do verbo **estar**:

> Quanto **está** escuro.

Acredito que no português do Brasil a <strike>única alternativa</strike> é utilizar o verbo **estar**. No português de Portugal ou outros paises de língua portuguesa existe possibilidade de usar o verbo **ser**?

Pergunta relacionada: [Difference between ser and estar.](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1062/difference-between-ser-and-estar)

[ATENÇÃO: A PERGUNTA ESTÁ SEM CONTEXTO NECESSITA SER EDITADA]

Comment: Bem-vindo ao site. Vou editar a tua pergunta, nomeadamente para se compreender logo pelo título do que é que se trata. É que já existe [outra pergunta com título parecido](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1062/difference-between-ser-and-estar), mas que é bastante diferente. Pode sempre desfazer as minhas alterações se não gostares delas.

Comment: Já cá tens a tua pergunta de volta.

Answer (score 2):

Sim, é possível usar ambas as frases.
E parece-me que seriam usos válidos também em Português do Brasil.

> - Quando tens mais medo? No lusco-fusco, ou quando está escuro?
> - Quando está escuro. Sem sombra de dúvida!

---

> - Quando é que é perigoso mergulhar no mar?
> - Quando é escuro. Se não vemos o fundo, não devemos mergulhar, não te lembras daquela campanha "[não mergulhes no escuro](http://www.scml.pt/pt-PT/destaques/nao_mergulhes_no_escuro/)"?!? (... E quando está bandeira vermelha, etc.)

Comment: No teu primeiro exemplo, não seria também possível responder, "Quando for escuro?" Já agora, não é "as frasew", é um nadinha mais à direita.

Comment: Seria, @Jacinto ; troquei de exemplo. Tentei usar *especificamente* a forma verbal que o autor da pergunta usou... embora me pareça que seria suficiente demonstrar um uso válido do mesmo verbo.

Comment: Mas para ilustrar a possibilidade de *ser*, eu até prefiro o exemplo "volto a casa quando for escuro" (*estiver* também me parece bem) do que o do mar. Parece-me que o mais correto no caso do mar é "onde é escuro" e "quando está escuro."

Comment: Concordo. Mas não vejo maneira de revirar o discurso no exemplo para ficar assim.

Comment: Há [aqui](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1530/vers%C3%A3o-em-portugu%C3%AAs-ou-vers%C3%A3o-portugu%C3%AAs) uns comentários relevantes do OP, com exemplos que ele encontrou de "quando é escuro".

Answer (score 2):

No Brasil, diferenciamos assim:

Quanto a **Ser**

> É escuro: situação em que ser escuro é um aspecto natural, imutável e que não é alterado.
>
> Exemplo: "Você pode diferenciar a cobra venenosa de uma sem veneno pela sua mandíbula, quando é escura."
>
> Explicando a frase: Podemos ler, na frase, que existem cobras de mandíbulas escuras e claras, mas que elas não alteram de cor, são e ponto. Isso diferencia as espécies.

Quanto a **Estar**

> Está escuro: situação em que estar escuro é uma possibilidade, e não o fato do "escuro" sempre estar lá.
>
> Exemplo: "O céu, quando está escuro, representa a noite."
>
> Explicando a frase: O céu pode estar escuro e estrelado, porém, dentro de algumas horas, ele pode estar claro e iluminado pelo sol. O escuro se torna claro, é algo passageiro.

Obs: Eu não entendo nada de cobras, apenas utilizei uma situação hipotética para explicar o uso hahahahahaha.