# Regência Nominal: "Versão em português" ou "Versão português"

Tags: regência

É obrigatorio o uso da preposição **"em"**:

> versão **em** português(inglês/italiano)

ou

> versão português(inglês/italiano)

Exemplos:

> - Instagram ganha versão **em** português
> - Lepo Lepo ganha versão **em** inglês
> - A autora esteve no Salão divulgando a versão **em** francês da sua obra
> - Conheça a brasileira que canta a versão português do tema de Frozen

Referências de grámatica:

[Rêgencia Nominal](http://www.passeiweb.com/na_ponta_lingua/sala_de_aula/portugues/gramatica/sintaxe/gramatica_sintaxe_reg_verbal_nom_2_fase)

Comment: Seria interessante incluir na pergunta a motivação. Imagino que seja os muitos "versão português" que se encontram na net. Só agora, para responder à pergunta é que fui pesquisar, e me dei conta disso. (Já agora, foi uma pena teres apagado a pergunta de ontem. Tinha interesse, e a resposta não era nada óbvia. Se não gostaste da minha revisão, podias sempre clicar [edit] e voltar a mudar.)

Comment: @Jacinto Não te parece um pouco estranho falar em "regência" aqui?

Comment: @Lambie, terminologia não é o meu forte, mas pelo que vi no primeiro site que encontrei, ["Regência nominal é o nome da relação existente entre um nome (substantivo, adjetivo ou advérbio) e os termos regidos por esse nome"](https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/sint/sint71.php), parece estar bem: "em português" são termos regidos por "versão".

Comment: @Jacinto Nesta pergunta, o termo regência não tem cabimento aqui. em ou de não seriam "regidos" pela palavra versão. A palavra versão pode ou não está seguida de em.

Comment: @Lambie, a minha ideia foi que "versão" rege "em português" porque "em português" está dependente de "versão"; não tenho ideia que uma coisa regida seja obrigatória. Mas repito, terminologia gramatical não é o meu forte.

Comment: @Jacinto Versão em português ou versão portuguesa. Para mim, "versão português" seria um erro de concordância (em gênero e número) do substantivo com o adjetivo. Se fala em concordância nominal. Poxa...[sem irritação].:)

Comment: @Lambie, abre uma pergunta sobre o significado de *regência/regência nominal*. Eu, assim sem estudar melhor o assunto não sei dar uma resposta. Como podes ver na minha resposta abaixo, eu não usei essa terminologia.

Comment: @Jacinto Tudo bem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Há duas possibilidades gramaticalmente corretas:

> (a) Versão em português.
>
> (b) Versão portuguesa.

Em (b) temos o adjetivo *portuguesa*, que tem que concordar em género com *versão*.
Em (a), *português* é substantivo: a língua portuguesa. A preposição ***em*** é necessária para ligar os dois substantivos. É como dizer "versão em língua portuguesa." Do mesmo modo:

> *Bíblia em português*
>
> *Tradução em português* ou *tradução portuguesa*
>
> *Declaração Universal dos Direitos Humanos em português.*

Agora, na net encontra-se com grande frequência "versão português." A única maneira de entender isto gramaticalmente é considerar *português* como o nome da versão, à semelhança de *versão A.* Para mim, isto é aceitável num nome dum produto, especialmente com maiúsculas, como em [Netscape Versão Português](http://www31.receita.fazenda.gov.br/pirgateway/calcpfNetscape_Versao_Portugus.html). Já numa canção com versões em várias línguas, [Ingênua (versão português)](http://www.vagalume.com.br/dulce-maria-solo/ingenua-versao-portugues.html) parece-me uma alternativa desleixada ou "moderna" a *Ingênua (versão portuguesa)* ou *(versão em português)*.

Comment: Quando temos «versão português», é provável tratar-se duma justaposição de substantivo. Nessa estrutura, o normal é deixar o substantivo modificador sem flexão — mas com o passo do tempo, alguns passam a formar-se em plural etc. Também seria interessante mencionar que «versão portuguesa» é ambíguo: pode ser uma versão na língua portuguesa *o* uma versão procedente de Portugal. Com «versão em português», não a há.

Comment: Que é justaposição de substantivos (e não falta de concordância em género entre adjetivo e substantivo) eu não duvido. A questão relevante é: porquê justapor os substantivos *versão* e *português* em vez de os ligar com preposição ***em***? Vamos também começar a dizer *concordância género* em vez de concordância em género, ou *luz sol* em vez de luz do sol?

Comment: É a pergunta, sim. Não sei se o português está a experimentar o mesmo, mas no castelhano a justaposição está em auge forte. A verdade é que poderia imaginar usos de «luz sol» mas como forma de identificação e não de descrição (não sei se me explico bem)

Comment: Versão tem dois sentidos, né? Exercício escolar que consiste na tradução para a língua do aluno. O oposto de:  retroversão (version et thème em francês). Oqueque {:)} se faz com isso? :) Versão também é variante: os seus exemplos são disso ou não? O história confusa (na minha cabeça). Ou seja a semântica....Aiuto. :)

"versão", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2013, https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/vers%C3%A3o [consultado em 23-08-2018].

Answer (score 1):

Versão em português

Versão portuguesa

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Portuguese Language! Tente sustentar a sua resposta com pelo menos uma justificação e se possível fontes dessa informação. Faça o nosso [tour] e aprenda como perguntar e responder aqui no site.