# Como evitar confusão entre o verbo SER e ESTAR, na aprendizagem?

Tags: verbos, ser-estar

Quando um não-nativo está aprendendo português, quais são os principais casos em que os verbos "ser" e "estar" podem causar confusão?

Comment: Para os falante nativos da língua Inglesa, ou qualquer outra língua onde "ser" e "estar"  sejam expressos pela mesma palavra, frequentemente haverá confusão.  Mesmo com a explicação de que "ser refers to a permanent condition" e "estar is temporary" ainda assim haverá maior ou menor grau de confusão dependendo do grau de fluência dos interlocutores.

Comment: Acho que talvez esta pergunta deva ser fechada como duplicado [desta]. Há também [outras threads](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/search?q=ser+estar) relacionadas no pt.se.

Comment: Acho que o @bad_coder quis linkar para essa questão: [Difference between ser and estar](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/1062/2764).

Comment: @stafusa sim, queria linkar essa pergunta e também a pesquisa. Fiz um erro a escrever o link.

Comment: Acho que a melhor maniera é seguir a regra até pisar na jaca. Os erros são o melhor professor, na minha humilde opinião.

Comment: @zewill Você considera essa [pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/1062/2764) uma duplicata da tua?

Comment: Considerei deixar essa pergunta aberta por duas razões: 1) ser em português, enquanto a duplicada mais óbvia é em inglês, e 2) focar na aprendizagem. Opto por fechar porque 1) traduções das respostas à duplicada podem ser facilmente adicionadas, e essa de qualquer forma é uma dúvida mais relevante para não falantes de português; e 2) pontos mais sutis/difíceis podem ser inferidos das respostas à duplicada e também são bastante dependentes do contexto de aprendizagem. Em caso de discordância, basta votar para reabrir.